# como puedo mover un elemento canvas desde javascript, asi como si fuera un personaje?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

en estado intentando con
para mover el personaje lo que ocuerre es que se actualiza tan rapido que pareciera que se extendio en ves de moverse. me di cuenta de esto despues mover el canvas mas pixeles de los que es su alto o ancho.
intente tambien hacer lo mismo con el eje x pero el resultado es el mismo parece que lo que esta cambiando es el width , o ek height pero ya revise que que no... haasta que termine aqui para pedir ayuda sobre. cabe destacar que hace unos meces tambien estaba tratando de hacer algo similar pero menos trabajado y consegui justo esto un "personaje" que ne ves de moverse se "extiende"?, sin mencionar los problemas para hacer el "mapa", por favor alguien aconsejeme de como hacer un juego con javascritpt con tematica rpg :"(.

```js
var player_y = 0,
  player_x = 0,
  player_width = 10,
  player_height = 10;

window.onkeydown = tecla;

function tecla(event) {
  num = event.keyCode;
  //preven default
  event.preventDefault();
  // arriba / w
  if (num == 87) {
    player_y += 10;
    console.log('w');
    draw_player()
  }

  function draw_player() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("player");
    if (canvas.getContext) {
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
      ctx.fillRect(player_x, player_y, player_width, player_height);

    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("Texturas/Entorno/cested_tx.png");
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

#player {
  margin: 20px;
  border: black 1px solid;
  background: url('Texturas/Player/player_state_3.png');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="player" width="64px" height="64px">Tu navegador no soporta canvas</canvas>

<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="stats.js"></script>
<script src="map.js"></script>
<script src="player.js"></script>
<script src="armas.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

¡Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español!

Para este tipo de aplicación debes de recordar siempre "limpiar" tu canvas antes de dibujar.

Tienes un objeto(en tu caso es un jugador) con sus respectivas coordenadas y lo que haces es leer estas propiedades y dibujar donde el esté **actualmente**. Estos datos son los únicos que te importan y los que vas a querer dibujar; lo que tu personaje haya hecho anteriormente no nos importa, debemos borrar la pantalla (generalmente exceptuando el fondo) y volver a dibujar (renderizar) los objetos según sus propiedades actuales.

Puedes limpiar tu `canvas` haciendo:

```
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

```js
var player_y = 0,
  player_x = 0,
  player_width = 10,
  player_height = 10;

window.onkeydown = tecla;

function tecla(event) {
  num = event.keyCode;
  //preven default
  event.preventDefault();
  // arriba / w
  if (num == 87) {
    player_y += 10;
    console.log('w');
    draw_player()
  }

  function draw_player() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("player");
    if (canvas.getContext) {
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      //Limpia tu canvas antes de dibujar el nuevo frame!
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
      ctx.fillRect(player_x, player_y, player_width, player_height);

    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("Texturas/Entorno/cested_tx.png");
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

#player {
  margin: 20px;
  border: black 1px solid;
  background: url('Texturas/Player/player_state_3.png');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="player" width="64px" height="64px">Tu navegador no soporta canvas</canvas>

<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="stats.js"></script>
<script src="map.js"></script>
<script src="player.js"></script>
<script src="armas.js"></script>
```

Vas muy bien con tu juego, todos pasamos por estas mismas cosas al inicio, te invito a ver [este video tutorial](https://codigofacilito.com/cursos/snake-con-html5) (no es mío)  que explica algunos conceptos básicos que te ayudarán, de igual manera cuando tengas una duda aquí estará la comunidad para ayudarte, no desesperes, muchas veces, aún para alguien con experiencia programar no es un proceso rápido.

P.d.: ¡Te invito también a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que obtengas tu primera medalla!

Comment: hermano demasiadas gracias, HEROE

Comment: Con mucho gusto, la mejor manera de contribuir al sitio es marcar la respuesta como válida para que los demás usuarios puedan tener acceso a esta información cuando busquen un problema que se asemeje al tuyo.

Answer (score 0):

Aca te dejo un ejemplo de como lo resolvi yo

```
<script>
    var name = parseFloat(prompt("Escribe el nombre de tu personaje"));
    var canvasC = document.getElementById("CanvasG");
    var pant = canvasC.getContext("2d");
    var anchoPantalla = 1720;
    var altoPantalla = 758;
    var teclap = 0;
    var personajeAnimado = false;

    var backgroundImg = new Image();
    backgroundImg.src = "component1.png";

    backgroundImg.onload = function () {
        var sprite = new Image();
        sprite.src = "link.png";
        var indiceX = 0;
        var indiceY = 0;
        var linkX = 0;
        var linkY = 0;

        function dibujarPersonaje() {
            pant.drawImage(sprite, indiceX * 32, indiceY * 32, 32, 32, linkX, linkY, 90, 90);
            indiceX = indiceX + 1;
            if (indiceX > 4) {
                indiceX = 0;
            }
        }

        function dibujaCanvas() {
            pant.drawImage(backgroundImg, 0, 0, anchoPantalla, altoPantalla);
            if (personajeAnimado) {
                dibujarPersonaje();
            } else {
                pant.drawImage(sprite, 0, 0, 32, 32, linkX, linkY, 90, 90);
            }
            pant.fillStyle = 'white';
            pant.font = 'italic bold 18pt Times New Roman';
            pant.fillText("Tecla Presionada: " + teclap + ", X: " + linkX + " Y: " + linkY, 10, 30, (anchoPantalla - 10));
            requestAnimationFrame(dibujaCanvas);
        }

        document.onkeydown = function (event) {
            if (event == null) {
                teclap = window.event.keyCode;
            } else {
                teclap = event.keyCode;
                switch (teclap) {
                    case 83:
                        linkY = linkY + 20;
                        indiceY = 0;
                        personajeAnimado = true;
                        break;
                    case 65:
                        linkX = linkX - 20;
                        indiceY = 1;
                        personajeAnimado = true;
                        break;
                    case 87:
                        linkY = linkY - 20;
                        indiceY = 2;
                        personajeAnimado = true;
                        break;
                    case 68:
                        linkX = linkX + 20;
                        indiceY = 3;
                        personajeAnimado = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        document.onkeyup = function (event) {
            personajeAnimado = false; // Cuando se suelta la tecla, detener la animación
        };

        requestAnimationFrame(dibujaCanvas);
    };
</script>
```

[image: (component1) esta es la imagen de fondo de prueba]
[[image: (link) imagen de frames]]